# vscode function who can tell me the parent selector in css/sass where the cursor is

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, css-selectors, selector, vscode-extensions

I want to add a feature for auto complet css selector in scss files who can handle the "&" in the *"HTML to CSS autocompletion"* extension on vscode.

For exemple :

```
.description{
  &__img{}
  &__text{}
}
```

The feature will understand that the cursor is in a block selector (".description"), and read all className and id in the html file and keep only who start with "description" in their className. And, when the user start his line with "&", it'll show a suggestion based on the className of the block selector where it is.
But, it have to replace the ".description" by "&".

For that, i have to know if the cursor is in a block selector but I don't know how can I do that, I don't know what I have to import from vscode dependencies (I didn't found it in the documentation)

Thanks

Comment: first you have to find which HTML **files** are using this SCSS file. Then parse these HTML files and locate the **tag(s)** with the block selector, and find the child selectors/tags.